# The less than selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('li:lt(5)').css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="listes">
    <ul id="ul1">
        <li>
            Element de liste 1
            <ul id="ul2">
                <li>Enfant 1</li>
                <li>Enfant 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Element de liste 2</li>
        <li>Element de liste 3</li>
        <li>Element de liste 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am expecting the last 2 `li`'s to stay intact, but only the last one is.

*(From the docs: The `:lt()` selector selects all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.)*

What's the reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: Your first stop should always be [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), which is quite clear about the indexes being 0-based.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure I did, I just missed that part. I'm new to jQuery's docs

Comment: `I'm new to jQuery docs` ... that statement makes no sense

Comment: What I meant is that it's not very clear to me. But I'm sure that with time & practice, it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is **zero-based**. To select the first five elements use

```
$('li:lt(4)')
```

From jQuery Documentation of [`:lt() selector`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):<sup>(Emphasis is mine)</sup>

> `indexFromEnd`: Zero-based index, counting backwards from the last element.
>
> Note that since **JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact**. This is why `$( ".myclass:lt(1)" )` selects the first element in the document with the class `myclass`, rather than selecting no elements. In contrast, `:nth-child(n)` uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li:lt(4)').css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="listes">
  <ul id="ul1">
    <li>
      Element de liste 1
      <ul id="ul2">
        <li>Enfant 1</li>
        <li>Enfant 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Element de liste 2</li>
    <li>Element de liste 3</li>
    <li>Element de liste 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I totally missed the 0-based-indexed fact